# OpenVpn cannot ping the server from interla LAN

Tags: openvpn

I configured OpenVPN on a FW (Centos8) in this way:

```
Remote Client
↓dev ens6
Server (OpenVpn + Firewalld) 10.14.128.29
↓dev ens7
Internal Lan (10.14.128.0/24)
↓                      ↓
A (10.14.128.13)     B(10.14.128.14)
```

`A` can ping `B`. `A/B` can't ping Server. Why?

I suspect something is missing in the routing table of Server.
My `/etc/openvpn/server.conf`

```
# OpenVPN Port, Protocol, and the Tun
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun

# OpenVPN Server Certificate - CA, server key and certificate
ca /etc/openvpn/server/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/server/ca.crt
key /etc/openvpn/server/pkki.key

#DH and CRL key
dh /etc/openvpn/server/dh.pem


# Redirect all Connection through OpenVPN Server
server 10.14.128.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 10.14.128.0 255.255.255.0"
push "redirect-gateway def1"

# Using the DNS from https://dns.watch
push "dhcp-option DNS 84.200.69.80"
push "dhcp-option DNS 84.200.70.40"
# Redirect all Connection through OpenVPN Server
server 10.14.128.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 10.14.128.0 255.255.255.0"
push "redirect-gateway def1"

# Using the DNS from https://dns.watch
push "dhcp-option DNS 84.200.69.80"
push "dhcp-option DNS 84.200.70.40"

#Enable multiple clients to connect with the same certificate key
duplicate-cn

# TLS Security
cipher AES-256-CBC
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA256:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-CBC-SHA256
auth SHA512
auth-nocache
```

The resulting routing table

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         xxx.xxx.xxx.1   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens6
0.0.0.0         xxx.xxx.xxx.1   0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 ens7
10.14.128.0     10.14.128.2     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.14.128.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 ens7
10.14.128.2     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
xxx.xxx.xxx.1   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 ens6
xxx.xxx.xxx.1   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    101    0        0 ens7
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was very simple. I used the same addresses space for both sub-networks, the remote and the internal one.
It was enough to change this line:

```
server 10.14.128.0 255.255.255.0
```

to

```
server 10.15.128.0 255.255.255.0
```